# instance variable is null for prepareForSegue method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a a simple view controller that loads a record from the database before showing a "Continue game" button. I record is loaded into the _company variable and I can confirm that this is populated correctly.

However, the variable is null when prepareForSegue runs.

It's very strange as I've tried creating a string instance at the same times as when the _company variable gets updated and this is available in the prepare... method.

```
// StartScreenViewController.h

@interface StartScreenViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *continueGameButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) Company *company;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *name;

- (void)setupGameButtons;
- (void) getSavedGame;

@end


// StartScreenViewController.m

@implementation StartScreenViewController

@synthesize continueGameButton = _continueGameButton;
@synthesize company = _company;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{  
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupGameButtons];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
//    self.company = nil;
    [self setContinueGameButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)setupGameButtons {
    [self getSavedGame];
    if (_company == nil) {
        _continueGameButton.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (void)getSavedGame {
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[Company entityName]];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", nil]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:30];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:30];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];
    NSArray *results = [[[DomainDataModel sharedDataModel] mainContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];    
    _company = [results objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"company name:: %@", [_company name]);
//    [self getSavedGame];
    if ([@"continue_game" isEqualToString:[segue identifier]]) {
        DashboardViewController *controller = (DashboardViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.company = _company;

    }
}

@end
```

Would appreciate any help on this as it has me completely stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this declared as a weak property? Who owns this property? I have a feeling that changing this declaration to strong should do the trick.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *continueGameButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Company *company;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

Comment: Thanks - looks like I need to learn some more about these different types :)

Comment: The way I see it - if you don't know the difference you should stop anything else and learn objective c. Be respectful of the technology :)

Comment: I prefer a learn as you go approach - don't wanna over-respect the stuff ;)